# A class that can't be instantiated

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    internal Person()
    {
        this.Name = "Ian";
    }

    public static Person Initialize()
    {
        return new Person();
    }
}
```

Because the constructor is internal, the compiler will throw a compilation error "The type Person has no constructors defined" when an external assembly tries to instantiate `Person`. This is the intended behavior because I want users to instantiate the class thru the static `Initialize` method like so:

```
Person p = Person.Initialize();
```

However, the IntelliSense is still showing `Person` as an instantiable class (it is listed after you type the `new` keyword).

Is there a way to "hide" the constructor in the IntelliSense because it is misleading? Or something is wrong with my design?

**EDIT:** 
The question is how to "hide" the constructor in the IntelliSense because it is misleading.

Open your Visual Studio and type the following:

```
System.IO.TextReader a = new
```

As you can see, there is no `TextReader` in the Intellisense that is being highlighted. Now try the `Person` and the `Person` "constructor" will automatically be highlighted.

What I want is the TextReader IntelliSense "behavior".

Comment: Try making the constructor `private`, not `internal`

Comment: A quick guess would be to explicitly add the `private` keyword to your `Person` method. But why is it important that the constructor not be called directly?

Comment: Internal means that it will be visible within the same `namespace`. Have you made sure that the class using `Person` is not in the same namespace? Otherwise see @Rob's comment.

Comment: @Rob: Still the same IntelliSense behavior.

Comment: @Kevin: No, [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) means that a member is visible only within the same *assembly*. It doesn't have anything to do with namespaces.

Comment: @Kevin: It is in a different assembly.

Comment: `System.IO.TextReader` is an `abstract` class. You'll get the same behavior if you mark your class as `abstract`. And of course, an abstract class can still have protected constructors.

Comment: That is not a Singleton. Every time you call Initialize you will get  a new instance. Its more a Factory pattern, your Initialize method will create new instances of your class.

Comment: Make the class `abstract`. You cannot make instances of `abstract` classes :). @Cody Gray, @Ian: Thanks.

Comment: @Mongus Pong: You are right. This is more like a "factory".

Answer (score 3):

**internal** means it is accessible in the entire assembly. So that's why the IntelliSense still shows the constructor.

What you want is **private** or **protected**.

**private** means it can only be called within the class.

**protected** means it can be called from within the class, and all the derived classes. (This is a good choice if you want to derive from a singleton class).

For more about accessibility: [Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is called "Singleton"...

this is the basic design of a class like this:

```
public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

more Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: The code in the question is not a Singleton. Just because it has a factory method does not automatically make it want to be a singleton.